# how can i add Models to a list by a fuction in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, function, model

Let's assume we have a Model class like this:

```
`class add_ingredients_list {
   String? Ingredient_name;
   String? Ingredient_mass; 
   String? Ingredient_mass_unit;


   add_ingredients_list(
   this.Ingredient_name,
   this.Ingredient_mass, 
   this.Ingredient_mass_unit,
   );

  }`
```

and this `List<add_ingredients_list> added_ingredients_list =  [];`

now I want to use a function to add Models to this list based on variables for
Ingredient_name,
Ingredient_mass,
Ingredient_mass_unit

can anyone give me a sample Code snipped with random values? How the function would look like?

Comment: What is the part that you are struggling with?

Comment: idk how i should write it in code can someone give me a example code

Comment: Please follow the naming conventions for capitalization and use of underscores.

Comment: your class name and instance are having same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply add Models to this list based on variables, you can create a function like this:

```
void addIngredients(){

List<add_ingredients_list> added_ingredients_list =  [];


 add_ingredients_list instance1 = add_ingredients_list("Ingredient1Name", "IngredientMass", "IngredientUnit") //create an example instance of the class

  added_ingredients_list.add(instance1);

 }
```

If you want to get the list, you can make the function type of List<add_ingredients_list> and return your list.

If you want to say retrieve values and then add, you can add parameters to your function and then use those values in that instance created.

```
void addIngredients(String? name, String? mass, String? massUnit)
{
    //add these values to the list
 }
```

Note, this is just a very basic example of it.
If you want a specific solution, you would need to provide more context for your problem.

Comment: Thats all I needed, thank you very much